# Como arreglo la excepcion java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

**Mi programa lleva objetos que son propuestas, como documentos. Estos van dentro de materiales, de los cuales se arman jornadas para conversar acerca de esos temas propuestos en los materiales.
El error de puntero Me pasa con un objeto, pero este está como parámetro de un método de otra clase. Ayuda
no puedo inicializar un objeto, verdad?**

*Me dice que no se puede acceder a getOrigen() porque e es null*

```
public boolean guardar(Propuesta e) {

        int filasAfectadas = 0;
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            //conectar con bd
            c = conectar();
            //consulta SQL
            String sql = "INSERT INTO `Propuesta` (`origen_propuesta`, `titulo_propuesta`, `descripcion_propuesta`, `categoria_propuesta`, `autor_propuesta`, `fecha_propuesta`, `motivacion_propuesta`, `estado_propuesta`, `motivoRechazo_propuesta`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
            
            PreparedStatement pStmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            pStmt.setString(1, e.getOrigen()); // acá me dice que no se puede acceder a getOrigen() porque e es null
            pStmt.setString(2, e.getTitulo()); // lo mismo para estos...
            pStmt.setString(3, e.getDescripcion());
            pStmt.setString(4, e.getCategoria());
            pStmt.setString(5, e.getAutor());
            pStmt.setString(6, e.getFecha());
            pStmt.setString(7, e.getMotivacion());
            pStmt.setString(8, e.getEstado());
            pStmt.setString(9, " ");
            

            filasAfectadas = pStmt.executeUpdate();
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace(); // esto me imprime el error
            
        } finally {
            try {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return filasAfectadas != 0;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Tu error no está en el código que muestras. La función `guardar(Propuesta e)` recibe ese `e` como nulo, tienes que revisar donde estas llamando a esa función